# Nginx reverse proxy apache2 High CPU load

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, wordpress, central-processing-unit

my server:
2x Intel Xeon 5506 2.13GHz
24 GB DDR3 RAM
Debian 5.0.8 64-bit

My server CPU is aroung 90% at 600 users and around 6 page views per second.

There are 2 Sites on the server. One Forum with low visitors and a Wordpress page.

[image: http://www.abload.de/img/unbenanntvbym5.png]

My Apache configurations:

```
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

KeepAliveTimeout 15

ServerLimit 500
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
StartServers          5
MinSpareServers       5
MaxSpareServers      10
MaxClients          250
MaxRequestsPerChild 1000
</IfModule>

<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
StartServers          2
MaxClients          250
MinSpareThreads      25
MaxSpareThreads     150
ThreadsPerChild      25
MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
StartServers          2
MaxClients          250
MinSpareThreads      25
MaxSpareThreads     150
ThreadsPerChild      25
MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

<IfModule mpm_event_module>
StartServers          2
MaxClients          150
MinSpareThreads      25
MaxSpareThreads      75 
ThreadLimit          64
ThreadsPerChild      25
MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```

Comment: what is nginx configuration, does static file served from nginx?

Comment: If still not resolved this issue, try this... KeepAliveTimeout 5